# How to define asynchronous build functions in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, dart, async-await, mobile-development

I am writing a widget for a Flutter mobile app and I have written a function to fetch weather information from an API.  The API functions is an async function, that uses await to go back and get the information after the API call returns.  Here is the simplest code possible.

```dart
Future<Int> getTemp() async {
    // get api call
    return temp
}

class TempTextState extends State<WeatherData> {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) async {
         return Text(await getTemp());
    }
}
```

This seems like it would work, but then I realize that async functions must return Futures, and build returns a Widget, not a FutureWidget.  I want to use asynchronous functions to fetch data for me, but I can't think of a way to use async functions in a non-async function.   How do I escape async hell?

Answer (score 0):

Flutter has same options async-await article also best practices use  [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html). If you want service call the first time, write your code init state.
I'm adding example future builder code => [Repo](https://github.com/VB10/stack-over-help-flutter/tree/master/lib/async_func)

- I'm adding example future builder code and your => [Repo(All Example)](https://github.com/VB10/stack-over-help-flutter/tree/master/lib/async_func)

Look at your code example:
[image: Future request]